# Application launching 100% in debug but not in real life

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2012, mvvm

I have looked all over the web but did not find anything that could help me out here.

I run Windows 8 with my beloved VS 2012 and my PC has the 4.5 framework.

I have developed a WPF C# application that I am targeting for the 4.0 Framework.

When I run it in debug mode in VS 2012 it runs perfectly but when I publish to my publish folder, run setup.exe and try to run the app, nothing happens. It does not give me any error messages but it also doesn't show any window, as if it weren't doing anything.

Is this an issue some folks have run into and if so, how can I remedy?

What info do you need? I am running the app through a bootstrapper and MVVM model; nothing extravagant.

Comment: try to restart the clickonce process.

Comment: Try to check System Event Logs for errors. If something went wrong there must be information somewhere.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: My event log says I have a :"
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll" error

Comment: Are you running it on the same machine with VS2012 on it?  Or a different one with .NET 4?  The reason is that .NET 4.5 updates WPF to 4.5, even when you target .net 4.. if you are using 4.5 features in WPF this can cause problems.

Comment: @Anubis1233 how can i "restart the clickonce process"?

Comment: @touyets This is not the problem with the upgraded infos. But thats how: restarting the process in task manager with description clickonce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be a very tricky thing to fix. You have a number of options:

First, open Task Manager, then look to see if a new Process appears when you start your published application. If no process for your application is added, then you *really* have problems. However, if a process does appear, then you can attach your Visual Studio to this process to debug it. Please refer to the [Attach to Running Processes with the Visual Studio Debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/3s68z0b3.aspx) page at MSDN for help with this.

If you can't do that, then you pretty much have to try to find the offending code without help. You'll need to edit the code to pop up loads of message boxes with the values of various objects to see if any of them are unexpectedly `null`. You can use common sense with this... this will never cause you a problem:

```
int value = 0;
```

Whereas this is much more likely to:

```
FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
```

In the latter case, add something like this afterwards:

```
MessageBox.Show(string,Format("path value: {0}", path));
```

One last point to make is that if the main `Window` does not appear, then your problem could well be in your constructor. If you can't debug your published version, then I really wish you good luck in finding the problem... it *could* be quite difficult.

Comment: I ended up having to rewrite the whole solution and it is now working. I reckon I missed a little error that I can not see.